# Displaying Data from One Component in Another

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react at the moment and I'm trying to have two components interact with each other. The hierarchy is as follows:

- App

  --SearchForm

  --Results

There's a data object that will be filtered through a string I enter in the *SearchForm* component. The filtered result should be displayed in the *Results* component. 
My logic was to have all the functions needed in the App component, and pass the data to the individual components.

I want to be able to display the filtered data in the results component.
Can anyone help me with this please?

Please find the *App.js* file's code below, as well as a sample of the object I'm using.

### App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Header from "./Header";
import SearchForm from "./SearchForm";
import Results from "./Results";
import Map from "./Map";

const Outer = styled.div`
    text-align:center;
`;


class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            query: "",
            data: [],
            refinedData: [],
        };
        // this.handleSearchChange = this.handleSearchChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleSearchChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            query: event.target.value,
        });
    }

    getData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4200/bookings");
        const json = await response.json();
        this.setState({
            data: json,
        })
        console.log(this.state.data);
    }

    filterData = () => {
        const filtered = this.state.data.filter(element => {
            return element.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.query.toLowerCase());
        });
        this.setState({
            refinedData: filtered,
        });
        console.log(this.state.refinedData);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getData();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Outer>
                <Header/>
                <SearchForm triggeredUpdate={this.handleSearchChange}/>
                <Results searchQuery={this.state.filterData}/>
                <Map/>
            </Outer>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

### Object

```
[
    {
        "id": 50000,
        "car": {
            "id": 1000,
            "licence_plate": "SKK5050Q"
        },
        "book_start": 1543271643,
        "book_end": 1543340723,
        "pickup": {
            "id": 87,
            "code": "WDL",
            "lat": 1.434,
            "lng": 103.78
        },
        "dropoff": {
            "id": 85,
            "code": "TPY",
            "lat": 1.33,
            "lng": 103.851
        },
        "user": {
            "id": 51498,
            "name": "Count Dooku"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: use state management techniques like MobX

Comment: @VilsadPP No need to use MobX or Redux here. At least not yet. @jerome, two questions: 1. Filter by what? It is an object, not an array. What you show here is not an object, it is an array which includes one object. So, filter by what? 2. You are defining a `refinedData` but passing a prop `filterData`. Is this deliberate or not? Since you don't have a state named `filiterData`, it is your function's name.

Comment: @devserkan 1. I put that object in the array called "this.state.data" and I want to filter the object in that array by the text I enter in the form. 2. I thought that I could call the function "filterData" through the "Results" component using a prop. So yes that was deliberate. 
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: 1. What you show here is not an object, it is an array :) If your API returns an object, then you are setting it in your state as an object. See: `this.setState({
            data: json,
        })` So, your `this.state.data` becomes an object. What does your API returns back? 2.`filterData` is the method name in your class, it is not in the state. So: `this.filterData.`How do you plan to trigger this function?

Comment: Also, one more question. Again, it is an object. For which part do you want to filter the array? You can't directly filter an object like that. For which property do you want to apply the filter. ie. `cat.license_plate`?

Comment: @devserkan 1. So my api returns an array of objects, and I thought I could set the state with that array of objects because I defined it as such `this.state = { data: [ ], }`. 2. About triggering that function, I am not sure how that can be triggered, so I thought I could do that through passing it as a prop to the results component. Not such a good idea looking back  :)

Comment: @devserkan 3. I thought I could filter the whole object. My bad with that one! Does that mean I should write and trigger different functions to filter for different fields such as `name`, `cat.license_plate`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179079/discussion-between-jerome-and-devserkan).

Comment: I've updated my answer and added another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple logic actually in `React`. You want to show filtered results in your `Results` component, then you pass the filtered state to it. You can trigger the search with a button, then maybe the suitable place for this can be `Search` component. For this, you will pass your `filterData` method to it as a prop as you think.

I said a few times "it is an array not object" in my comments since the last data you show in your question says **Object** as bold but it is an array :) So, I got confused but you are doing it right.

You should filter your data with a prop in your object. As you think again, like `user.name`, `car.license_late` etc. You need a target here.

Here is a simple working example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    query: "",
    data: [
      {
        "id": 50000,
        "car": {
          "id": 1000,
          "licence_plate": "SKK5050Q"
        },
        "book_start": 1543271643,
        "book_end": 1543340723,
        "pickup": {
          "id": 87,
          "code": "WDL",
          "lat": 1.434,
          "lng": 103.78
        },
        "dropoff": {
          "id": 85,
          "code": "TPY",
          "lat": 1.33,
          "lng": 103.851
        },
        "user": {
          "id": 51498,
          "name": "Count Dooku"
        }
      }
    ],
    refinedData: [],
  };

  handleSearchChange = event => this.setState({
      query: event.target.value,
    });


  filterData = () => {
    const { data, query } = this.state;
    const filtered = !query ? [] : data.filter(element =>
      element.car.licence_plate.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.query.toLowerCase())
    );
    this.setState({
      refinedData: filtered,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchForm filterData={this.filterData} triggeredUpdate={this.handleSearchChange} />
        <Results refinedData={this.state.refinedData} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Results = props => (
  <div>
  {
    props.refinedData.map( el =>
    <div key={el.id}>
      <p>ID: {el.id}</p>
      <p>User name: {el.user.name}</p>
    </div>
    )
  }
  </div>
)

const SearchForm = props => (
  <div>
    <input onChange={props.triggeredUpdate} />
    <br />
    <button onClick={props.filterData}>Search</button>
  </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Update after discussion on chat**

You can do the search without a button while you typing. We don't have `filterData` method anymore since we moved the filter logic into `handleSearchChange` method. Also, we don't need any `query` state right now.

`filterData` array created with a ternary operator. If there is no search `value` we are returning an empty array since we don't want to list all of our data if there is not any search. By the way, I've updated my previous solution according to that, too. It was returning all the data if we hit the `Search` button with an empty input.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      {
        "id": 50000,
        "car": {
          "id": 1000,
          "licence_plate": "SKK5050Q"
        },
        "book_start": 1543271643,
        "book_end": 1543340723,
        "pickup": {
          "id": 87,
          "code": "WDL",
          "lat": 1.434,
          "lng": 103.78
        },
        "dropoff": {
          "id": 85,
          "code": "TPY",
          "lat": 1.33,
          "lng": 103.851
        },
        "user": {
          "id": 51498,
          "name": "Count Dooku"
        }
      }
    ],
    refinedData: [],
  };

  handleSearchChange = event => {
    const { value: query } = event.target;
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const filteredData = !query ? [] : prevState.data.filter(element =>
        element.car.licence_plate.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())
      );

      return {
        refinedData: filteredData
      };
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchForm triggeredUpdate={this.handleSearchChange} />
        <Results refinedData={this.state.refinedData} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Results = props => (
  <div>
    {
      props.refinedData.map(el =>
        <div key={el.id}>
          <p>ID: {el.id}</p>
          <p>User name: {el.user.name}</p>
        </div>
      )
    }
  </div>
)

const SearchForm = props => (
  <div>
    <input onChange={props.triggeredUpdate} />
  </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```